# "Did you do it?" vs "Have you done it?"?

Tags: present-perfect, simple-past

If someone did something that made me mad, which is correct to say:

- *Did you do it?*
- *have you done it?*

If not, what is the proper situation for saying *Did you do it?*

Comment: *Why did you do it* is a fine way to ask about an event done in the past. *Why have you done it* implies there are consequences in the present still. *Did you do it* asks: are you the person who did this/that?

Comment: if there's consequences on me is it correct to say that to rebuke him?

Comment: Why did you do it is often good enough. Why have you done it would be appropriate for something that is going to or is still harming someone, for example, someone is going to lose a job or a friendship over it.

Comment: can I use "have you done it?" to rebuke somebody?

Comment: If you already know who has done it, no. It gives the person the opportunity to say, no. If he has done it, a more proper rebuke would be to ask *why* he has done it.

Answer (score 11):

“Have you done it?” is the question to ask if you want to know:

- whether a task is finished, or
- whether they have experience with some task.

For example, if you want to know whether a report is done, or whether somebody has gone sky diving before, you can ask, “Have you done it?” In the first case, you could also ask, “Have you done it yet?” In the latter, “Have you done it before?”

“Did you do it?” is the question you want to ask to find out **who** did something. You can also use it to ask whether a task is finished, although the emphasis is different:

> Did **you** do it?
>   Did you **do** it?

Comment: +1, but there is considerable room for flexibility here. 'Have you ever done it' can be a way of asking if someone has ever borrowed the keys to the wine cellar and helped themselves.

Comment: Good point, @WS2! I wouldn't use it that way for a recent occurrence though.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know someone did something to make you mad, you wouldn't ask if they had done it. You might question WHY they did it though:

> "Why'd you do it?"

However, if you are uncertain, then:

> "Did you do it?"

would be correct.